# Difference between HOT and WARM app start

Tags: android, startup

Please, If someone can explain, what is the difference between hot start and warm start, for android apps?
Here [Startup times](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#time-initial)

for HOT and WARM start it says, that is start when app is closed then opened again that's how I am understood..

Comment: This is explained here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#cold; what it basically says that a warm start is somewhere between cold and hot.

Comment: I agree that warm start is somewhere between cold and hot, but If I close app with back button and relaunch it,it should be warm start? Is it possible to simulate back button pressed through code?

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#internals) actually explain the difference.

**Hot start**

> In a hot start, all the system does is bring your activity to the foreground. If all of your application’s activities are still resident in memory, then the app can avoid having to repeat object initialization, layout inflation, and rendering.

**Warm start**

A warm start is similar to a hot start, but it has more overhead, for example:

- The OS removes your app from memory. On the next launch, the process and the activity need to be recreated, but the task can benefit from the saved instance state and other optimizations Android does for you.
- The app must recreate the activity from scratch.